arreglar un error de Node, no puede encontrar un entry en package.json
Si es que no se entiende mucho perdón, no se de programación y solo quería usar un código de github
Hola, es  mi primera vez usando esta pagina, tengo un problema tratando de usar un codigo, yo quería editar el archivo loc.csv para el juego papers please y después exportarlo en .zip (la pagina de el builder), el problema es que no funciona bien
al tratar de ejecutar el comando node . --csv C:\Users\ep1ku\Downloads\pn.csv --url https://paperspleaseloc.github.io --out C:\Users\me\Desktop\- salta el error de: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry intenté de muchas maneras solucionar el problema, tratando de instalar de nuevo npm, borrando package-lock.json, copiar un package.json y reemplazarlo, pero siempre salta el mismo error, por lo que entiendo no puede encontrar una parte de package.json, ya que dice module not found pero aún no puedo hacer nada
sé de que el codigo en si no lo probaron demasiado, pero ya llevo desde ayer tratando de resolver este prroblema

Revisa tu archivo package.json, debe tener dentro algo como "main": "index.js",
